# Is it possible to thicken lines that share geometry with other lines proportionately to the number of lines above or below?

Tags: qgis

I have a number of bus routes, which for certain parts of their length share the exact same geometry and therefore appear as only a single line. Can I style those parts or segments of the lines that overlap exactly other lines?

Conceptually it is similar to the "rule-based" render for points that overlap. So, for example, a segment that shared its geometry with 3 others might have a lineweight of 3x, a segment overlapping with 2 a lineweight of 2x, a line by itself a lineweight of x.

NB: I don't want to actually offset the lines or use transparency. Nor can I fudge it — this is a city-wide dataset, so it cannot be done manually. I want to assign a variable stroke weight based on the geometry that overlaps.

Comment: Are you willing to edit the data? If so, it's a simple matter of `explode lines`, then set the line width to `equaling_geom_count('Exploded')`. If not, you should look into virtual layers.

Comment: What software are you using? The answer is yes either way.

Answer (score 2):

A useful symbology. In QGIS, an "on the fly" solution using a stroke-width expression is likely possible, but may be too burdensome at render.

Since we generally deal with feature symbology, a basic solution involves using spatial operators like **Contains** on the features. With line features, when a whole feature is identical to another whole feature, they are 'contained'.

The following is a solution for this case, but with an additional step, can be extended to initial features where only part of their geometry is 'contained'.

1. With **Join Attributes by Location (Summary)** in the native QGIS processing library - join the line features with the condition **Contains** and select the **Summaries to calculate**: "Count"
2. Using the resulting "Count" attribute, in the *Symbology* tab, apply an expression on the **Stroke width** parameter with a data-defined override. You may need to scale the count value with some basic math:
   `(2+"count")/10`

In the likely case that only parts of features overlap, using this method, one could process the lines with **Explode lines** prior to the spatial join. This essentially carries the symbology down to the line segment level.

**Given that the spatial join involves data reduction, one downside with this approach is that useful attributes could be changed or lost thru summarizing.

[image: Image showing overlapping features with stoke-weighted symbology in black and original features in white]

Comment: Immensely helpful, thanks so much!